# Is there a python code to perform the following task in python

Tags: pandas, python-3.x

Is there a way by which I can find how many people rated below `60%` or how much percentage of people gave a rating of less than `60%`.

This is the sample rating for the product. Where a `6` represents `60%`. The data is currently stored in a pandas dataframe.

> 9
>   6
>   2
>   2
>   8
>   5
>   4
>   4
>   5
>   4
>   4
>   2
>   4
>   5
>   3
>   5
>   7
>   3
>   5
>   4
>   1

```py
dataset['Z32'].describe() # gives me a output 

count        24114.000000
mean         4.327445
std          2.086072
min          1.000000
25%          3.000000
50%          4.000000
75%          6.000000
max         10.000000

counts = dataset['Z32'].value_counts()
print(counts) 

5     5831
4     3722
3     3384
6     2874
1     2836
2     2218
7     1451
8     1040
9      416
10     342
```

Comment: put example data as text, not image.

Comment: I don't know what you have in dataset so I guess `len(dataset[ datase['z32] < 6 ])` ? Or maybe even shorter `sum(datase['z32] < 6)`

Comment: dataset is a rating on the scale of 1 to 10

Answer (score 1):

If `dataset` means `pandas.DataFrame` then you can use

```
dataset['rate'] < 6
```

to get dataset with values `True`/`False` which can sum because `True` is converted to 1 and `False` is converted to `0`

```
count = sum(dataset['rate']<6)  # 17
```

If you get number of all rows in dataset `len(dataset)` then you can calculate percentage value

```
percent = count/len(dataset)   # 0.8 (80%)
```

---

Working example

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame({
    'rate': [9, 6, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1]
})

count = sum(dataset['rate']<6)
percent = count/len(dataset)

print(count, percent, '{:.2%}'.format(percent))
```

Result

```
17 0.8095238095238095 80.95%
```